# Change a Storyboard Constraint Relation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble changing the relation on a constraint from storyboard. This is how the table view looks like at the moment. 
[image]

When the more button is click, I want the table view to look like this.
[image]

Okay, so I drag the bottom constraint from the imageView into my tableViewCell.swift file and named it **imageBottomConstraint**. I tried **imageBottomConstraint.relation = .greaterThan** but gives me an error saying that it's only a get, so the relation is equalTo and I'm trying to change it to greaterThan.

Here is were I'm confused and stuck, so I'm trying to create a new constraint but don't really understand **NSLayoutConstraint(item:, attribute:, relatedBy:, toItem:, attribute:, multiplier:, constant:)**. Don't understand item, attribute, relatedBy, toItem & attribute, can someone please help clarify.

My disaster code I thought would work but nope crashes instead.

```
@IBAction func showMoreBtn() {
    let item = imageBottomConstraint.firstItem
    let attribute1 = imageBottomConstraint.firstAttribute
    let relatedBy = NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual
    let item2 = imageBottomConstraint.secondItem
    let attribute2 = imageBottomConstraint.secondAttribute
    let multiplier = imageBottomConstraint.multiplier
    let constant = 12 

    let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: attribute1, relatedBy: relatedBy, toItem: toItem, attribute: attribute2, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 12)
}
```

So as you can see I don't know what I am doing, when creating constraint programmatic. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can Manage the Expected Behaviour in heightForRowAt Cell Delegate of TableView

```
/// Use this function to Set Height of TableCells
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
        {
            /// Is index Path More Button is cliked ?
            if indexPath.row == selectedIndex
            {
                /// If yes
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else
            {
                /// if No
                /// Provide a Static Height That will Set your requiremment
                return 160
            }
        }
```

**selectedIndex** its the index in which that more Button is Clicked , My requirement was to Expand one cell At a time, You can use a Array to manange the cells Need to be Expanded

Comment: What if the size of the label is higher than 160 pixels ;)

Comment: Label Height can also be Zero even if we provide Automatic dimension or not correct me if I am Wrong sir @RomOne , I just set an Example of 160 with a written comment above return 160 as it was suitable for my requirement so I just posted a comment line to make it vary as per requirement , its just a Example to Vary the Height of TableCell if required, in case label height is also less than image Height still the Automatic dimension will set the cell Height according to Image Height as that is also a part of cell

Comment: yeah I was being picky :) The OP will need to do some work on constraints to make sure the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works fine. Like adding some minimum constraint at bottom between the image and the superview. But fix sizes might not be a suitable solution because the hight of the label won't be known, the cell should grow with its content. Your code is still part of the solution :)

Comment: Yes for the same Either Developer will Provide a Static Height to Image with a Constraint or Developer will Provide Aspect height to image and a Height parameter to cell, to make this any one thing cell or image need to be of defined Height

Answer (score 0):

You might not use the right solution. I would use the fact that cells can expand and adapt to there content by using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
Here is a sample that could help you on your particular case:

https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

The idea would be:

- fix with a constraint the height of your label
- When you click the more button, you set that constraint to not active with `yourConstraint.active = false` and reload the cell by doing something like `yourTableView.reloadRows`

Comment: Thanks RomOne, will take a look at that article.

Comment: No worries, that technique is really helpful in many circonstancies, I use it quite often in my projects ;)

Comment: Don’t forget to upvote/accept answers that helped you ;)